# How to add a second location to a business in Google My Business

Tags: google-my-business

Our business is adding a second store.

How do we add this to Google My Business? (We already have our first store in GMB).

The articles on the web say to go to "My Locations" but this is nowhere to be seen in `business.google.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Create a Business Group

You can easily manage all of your business listings this way.

[image]

Create a group called "Example Company" and add as many locations as you like.

[image]

You can also bulk upload to make it easier. Just download all of the businesses you want like so:

[image]

---

When you're adding multiple locations here are some guidelines to follow:

1. Only create an additional listing if you *actually* have another
   *physical* location. Use a precise, accurate address and/or service area to describe your business location. P.O. boxes or mailboxes located at remote locations are not acceptable.
2. All locations must have the same name unless the business’s real world representation consistently varies from location to location. All locations must also have the same category if they provide the same service.

Read Google's [full guidelines for representing your business](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038177?hl=en#chains&zippy=%2Cineligible-businesses%2Celigible-businesses)

Answer (score 5):

It seems that adding additional locations to an existing GMB listing has been deprecated in favour of individual Business listings with their own location.

I am currently trying to do this myself and the only way I can find is to add a new business under the Businesses' section with the location name forming part of the new business name, otherwise, it'll just keep redirecting you to your existing GMB listing.

Comment: You are right. Just use the same name of Business and add new business. I found [this](https://professorm.org/google-my-business-training-free/how-to-add-another-location-to-google-my-business/) source, same info

Answer (score 0):

Explain in detail what exactly you need. Depending on the initial conditions, you can use different types of accounts.

Maybe this one [Advanced account setup](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/188487)

You can get help with [GMB support team](https://support.google.com/business/gethelp)